# How to create a string of texts and pass in position into ListView Adapter?

Tags: java, android

I want to create song lyrics up to 1500 in listview. When i tried to make up the list of song lyrics up to 900, i had an error while compiling with studio. The error states that ListViewAdapter class is hardcoded. This compilation error kept persisting.

So, i don't know how to code with SQlite and if really i want to code with SQlite i will then begin to type afresh the texts for the lyrics description

**Below is how i used to code it before now, until i decided to increase it to more than 900. Meaning i have been repeating the codes so as to get what i want. And on the process, the compilation gave error due to hard code;**

```
 //listview item clicks
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //code later
                if (modellist.get(i).getTitle().equals("Song 001 | This song lyrics 1")){
                    //start NewActivity with title for actionbar and text for textview
                    Intent intent =  new Intent(mContext, FavouritesContentActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("actionBarTitle", "Song 001");
                    intent.putExtra("contentTv", "This is song lyrics detail\n\n\n\n");
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                } if (modellist.get(i).getTitle().equals("Song 001 | This song lyrics 2")){
                    //start NewActivity with title for actionbar and text for textview
                    Intent intent =  new Intent(mContext, FavouritesContentActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("actionBarTitle", "Song 002");
                    intent.putExtra("contentTv", "This is song lyrics detail\n\n\n\n");
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                } if (modellist.get(i).getTitle().equals("Song 001 | This song lyrics 3")){
                    //start NewActivity with title for actionbar and text for textview
                    Intent intent =  new Intent(mContext, FavouritesContentActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("actionBarTitle", "Song 003");
                    intent.putExtra("contentTv", "This is song lyrics detail\n\n\n\n");
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                } if (modellist.get(i).getTitle().equals("Song 001 | This song lyrics 4")){
                    //start NewActivity with title for actionbar and text for textview
                    Intent intent =  new Intent(mContext, FavouritesContentActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("actionBarTitle", "Song 004");
                    intent.putExtra("contentTv", "This is song lyrics detail\n\n\n\n");
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                } if (modellist.get(i).getTitle().equals("Song 001 | This song lyrics 5")){
                    //start NewActivity with title for actionbar and text for textview
                    Intent intent =  new Intent(mContext, FavouritesContentActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("actionBarTitle", "Song 005");
                    intent.putExtra("contentTv", "This is song lyrics detail\n\n\n\n");
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                } if (modellist.get(i).getTitle().equals("Song 001 | This song lyrics 6")){
                    //start NewActivity with title for actionbar and text for textview
                    Intent intent =  new Intent(mContext, FavouritesContentActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("actionBarTitle", "Song 006");
                    intent.putExtra("contentTv", "This is song lyrics detail\n\n\n\n");
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                } if (modellist.get(i).getTitle().equals("Song 001 | This song lyrics 7")){
                    //start NewActivity with title for actionbar and text for textview
                    Intent intent =  new Intent(mContext, FavouritesContentActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("actionBarTitle", "Song 007");
                    intent.putExtra("contentTv", "This is song lyrics detail\n\n\n\n");
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }
//etc... up to 900 lyrics

            }
        });


        return view;
    }
```

***Now the code below is what i tried that slightly worked. The only issue i have now is the Lyrics description.***
`intent.putExtra("contentTv", modellist.get(i).getDesc());` *

the *getDesc()* draws its content from row.xml description...*

**This is what i tried that passed the description texts from row.xml**

```
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, FavouritesContentActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("actionBarTitle", modellist.get(i).getTitle());
        intent.putExtra("contentTv", modellist.get(i).getDesc());
        mContext.startActivity(intent);
     }
});
```

My question is how can create a string of texts and pass them in position using intent?

Comment: i can't understand  your problem please describe in brief

Comment: Please Provide more info on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I have made the question more clear for better understanding

Comment: @Joseph  please checkout answer below u need that?

Comment: ok i'm checking out

Comment: @Ghulam Qadir, the solution below didn't work. Can you help me with a better way of coding this ```intent.putExtra("contentTv", modellist.get(i).getDesc());``` such that it doesn't get the description from MainActivity

Comment: Yes if you didn't want to pass it through intent than u may use [Shared Preferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences) and get required data  anywhere .

Comment: please teach me how to use this SharedPreferences with this ListView

Comment: or give me an example that works with my project

Answer (score 1):

You have to create Recyclerview for showing large amount of items in list.

According to above problem you facing which i understand make a model class in which you first store all music title and description like i did below

First i make  model class name Music

```
public class Music {
    String title,description;
    public Music(String title, String description) {
        this.title=title;
        this.description=description;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title=title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description=description;
    }
}
```

Than I make  MusicAdapter class in which i inflate my music_item layout

```
public class MusicAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MusicAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private List<Music> musicList;
private Context context;

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView tvTitle;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super (view);

        tvTitle=view.findViewById (R.id.tvTitle);


    }
}


public MusicAdapter(Context context, List<Music> musicList) {
    this.musicList=musicList;
    this.context=context;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView=LayoutInflater.from (parent.getContext ())
            .inflate (R.layout.item_music, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder (itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
   Music musicItem=docsList.get (position);
    holder.tvValidatedDate.setText (musicList.get (position).getTitle ());
   holder.tvTitle.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener () {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           Intent intent =  new Intent (context, FavouritesContentActivity.class);
           intent.putExtra("actionBarTitle", musicItem.getTitle ());
           intent.putExtra("contentTv", musicItem.getDescription ());
           context.startActivity(intent);
       }
   });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return docsList.size ();
}
}
```

In the above adapter class you see on clicking each music item it's description get according to position of item and passed to next activity.

And in your activity create a music list and pass data from activity like below .

```
List<Music> musicList=new ArrayList<> ();
musicList.add (new Music ("Title 1","Description 1"));
musicList.add (new Music ("Title 2","Description 2"));
musicList.add (new Music ("Title 3","Description 3"));
musicList.add (new Music ("Title 4","Description 4"));
musicList.add (new Music ("Title 5","Description 5"));

MusicAdapter musicAdapter=new MusicAdapter (getContext (), musicList);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager (getContext ());
        recyclerview.setLayoutManager (mLayoutManager);
        recyclerview.setItemAnimator (new DefaultItemAnimator ());
        recyclerview.setAdapter (musicAdapter);
```

Comment: can you help provide me with some github example?

Answer (score 0):

You are using onClickListener(). You should use onItemClickListener()

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {

    //Do your stuff here with the position as index

    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, FavouritesContentActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("actionBarTitle", modellist.get(position).getTitle());
    intent.putExtra("contentTv", modellist.get(position).getDesc());
    mContext.startActivity(intent);

}
});
```